# How to see emails that were bounced off my yahoo email?

Tags: yahoo-mail, email-bounces

I never check my Yahoo email, and it seems like many emails were getting bounced off it. I've taken the measures to re-activate it, however I don't have access to those emails that were bounced off.

Is there anyway to retrieve those emails?

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to retrieve them short of asking all people who sent you the email during the period it was deactivated, to send the emails again